# Batch: find file and rename it / find file and delete it

Tags: file, batch-file, find, rename, delete-file

So... yes, Im pretty newbie. Still trying to explain as good as possible.
But needing help with such thing as finding exact file from C: drive (with batch),
and rename it.
Also wanted to know how to find file from C: and delete it. (2 problems in 1 thread...)

Problem 1. example: I want to find file called "text1.txt" from C: drive with batch,
if successfully found, rename it as "text2.txt".

Problem 2. example: I want to find file called "image1.jpg" from C: drive with batch,
if successfully found, delete it.

Or how this could be done with batch? del image1 only checks same folder where it already is, same with rename. How to find these files with batch from whole C: disk? 
Just example. 2 little things to solve, rename and delete by searching for exact files with batch. How about deleting file from subfolder with batch?
But sorry my low know-how, must start these things from somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it's great to have some good-loking programmers! Most programmers I know are **UGLY**.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d "text.txt"') do (ren "%%i" text2.txt)
```

Should do the rename task. You should prepend the drive and starting directory to the filename though, or it will rename ALL the `text.txt` files in ALL subdirectories. Hence `...dir /s/b "c:\users\kaster\text.txt"...` will process `"c:\users\kaster\"` and all of the directories below and rename ALL of the files named `text.txt` to the new name.

It works by performing a `DIR`scan in `/b` basic mode (ie filenames only) `/s` including subdirectories `/a-d` ignoring matching directory names for files named "text.txt" - and the full filename is assigned to `%%i`. The `delims` clause makes sure that any spaces are not interpreted as delimiters.

See

```
`FOR ?`
```

from the prompt for documentation.

ANd if you are executing this directly from the prompt, change each `%%` to `%`

The second command is substantially easire

```
del /s "image1.jpg"
```

Again, prepend the starting path, and be **VERY, VERY** careful. This will delete **ALL** filenames matching "image1.jpg" in and under the specified directory.

Throughout, quoting the filenames ensures that `spaces` in file or directorynames are correctly processed.

Comment: Thanks for tips! Btw, do you knnow why this rename thing works only when you dont run batch as admin? When running this rename batch file as admin, it will say "File not found", it works only when running it normally. And if you know how to make it work also when running as admin, how could I set it as always run ONLY as admin, that you couldn't even run it in normal mode, just for admins.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. If the output is OK, remove the `echo` command from the line.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d \file1.txt \image1.jpg') do if "%%~nxi"=="file1.txt" (echo ren "%%~i" "text2.txt") else if "%%~nxi"=="image1.jpg" echo del "%%~i"
```

Comment: Can I have these in 2 different commands? Another for find and rename named file, and another for find and delete named file? Would be bit easier to figure out purposes of both those with 2 different commands.