# Batch: find several folders and create file for each

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, xcopy

I am asking this in relation to this question: [Batch: find file and rename it / find file and delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689510/batch-find-file-and-rename-it-find-file-and-delete-it/15689899#15689899)
I am trying to do the same thing, except as the question states, I am trying to list all the users in and set each one to a variable, put a link to my program into the startup, then go to the next user, and do the same, but the users vary from workstation to workstation. So I need it to look at the folder name (in relation to the user account name of course) and use it as a variable in the xcopy command.. I am in a rush writing this, so let me know if you need any clarification, hopefully it makes sense. Thanks to anyone who helps! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the Rube Goldberg method of software deployment.  Just put a link to your program into the All Users profile.

```
copy shortcut.lnk "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
```

...and done.

I shudder to think of the maintenance nightmare your intended self-prescribed solution would cause.  What happens when a new version of the software needs to be deployed?  What if the updated version defaults to installing in a different directory than the previous?  What happens when a user gets a new computer and hands-me-down the existing one to an intern / GA / lower-level peon?  Goes on vacation and someone else fills in temporarily?  You really should do the "All Users" thing.

Or even better, include it in your domain policy login script.

Comment: Thank you. Can't say it solved it, but very good insight! (I almost have it anyhow.) 

P.S. sorry for the late response!

Comment: If it helps, you could instead add a `REG_SZ` value to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` pointing to the software you want to run at startup.